# How to resize QML TableView column to its contents on app start?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qt5, column-width

I am using Qt 5.9.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

When my application starts, I want to automatically adjust `TableView`'s column size to its contents. A model have some data on start.

I know about the `resizeColumnToContents` function, but I have no idea where to call it.

`onDataChange` does not work in `TableView`: The QML engine says that this signal does not exist. But intellitype allows me to type it in the code.

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 18/09/18

If you use a StackView or else you can preload your TableView

```
// main.qml

Loader {
   id: tableViewLoader
   active: true
   sourceComponent: TableView { id: tableView }
}

StackView {
id: stackView
initialItem: listViewLoader

function onContentReceived()
{
    stackView.push(tableViewLoader);
    tableViewLoader.item.resizeColumnsToContents()
}

function onContentClosed()
{
    swipeView.pop()
}

}
```

---

EDIT 17/09/18

You are right Danil.

There is specified in TableView.qml that

> ```
> Depending on how the model is populated, the model may not be ready when
> TableView Component.onCompleted is called. In that case you may need to
> delay the call to positionViewAtRow by using a \l {QtQml::Timer}{Timer}
> ```

For me this is working

```
Component.onCompleted: resizeColumnsToContentsTimer.start()

Timer {
    id: resizeColumnsToContentsTimer
    interval: 50
    running: false
    repeat: false
    onTriggered: parent.resizeColumnsToContents()
}
```

You can also see this discussion about it

http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-June/023018.html

---

Maybe, you can call it in onModelChanged which called when you set your model (your model must be populated before).

```
onModelChanged: tableView.resizeColumnToContents()
```

Otherwise, you can use signals/slots when your data ready.

But beware with this function : if you have delegate you must specify implicitWidth in, or this is will not to work.

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
    id: headerDelegate
    height: 36
    implicitWidth: textItem.implicitWidth + textItem.padding * 2
    color: Style.lightColor

    Text {
        id: textItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        padding: 10
        text: styleData.value
        elide: Text.ElideRight
        color: Style.darkColor
        font.pixelSize: Style.bigFontPixelSize
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not works: during call of a signal `onModelChanged` column count of `TableView` is zero.

Comment: Also, I tried `Timer`. It works only if `interval` is set to 2000 milliseconds. Of course, it is unacceptable.